# DDD | JPA - Design question that could involve sacrificing design for efficiency

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm quite new to DDD, but I love how the design enforces structure in your code (as long as you adhere to the principles). I have a conundrum where I believe in order to solve the problem, I need to sacrifice the design, which I don't want to do. But first off, I want to note that I may be designing this incorrectly from the start due to my ignorance.

I have an application that has an entity containing a BLOB in database terminology. Let's call this entity `child`. `child` is therefore hefty in size due to it containing a BLOB. Now, `child` can be found from its AR's identity, let's call AR `parent`. There's also another level higher, (`grandparent`), but this level isn't needed, as `child` contains the desired data to pass on to the user and `parent` can be found from the user's request (some complex searching is required on the application's side to retrieve parent, though).

Now, `parent` contains many of `child` (one-to-many relationship), but I only need one `child` per transaction, so querying the entire result of `parent` and `child` per request is definitely not needed. Executing this query for every transaction would also be incredibly inefficient, as I'm asking for lots of additional data from the DB that I'm not even using in every transaction. It would be exponentially more efficient to, for instance, keep `parent` locally, and execute a query for a single `child`.

I also have a tight SLA, so retrieving `child` needs to be incredibly quick. My current brute-force approach is to query `parent`, retrieve only one of `child`, and provide the result to the user. I'm looking for an approach where I can have `parent` locally, without the list of `child`, then when the request comes I query a single `child`. This would be incredibly quick and efficient, as I'm only retrieving what I need. But, this would break the rules of DDD, though, as `child` is technically only referenced by `parent`'s identity and wouldn't be its own AR.

Comment: You could try lazy-loading the blob while keeping the children collection. However, what rules forces you to have a collection of child into `parent`? Why can't `child` be it's own aggregate? Also, remember that your object model is meant to process commands, not queries. If you only fetch to display forget about your objects and go directly to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would do these steps:

1. Modify `ParentRepository` to load a parent with it's children and **without** their `BLOB` column. e.g. `@Query("select c.id, c.name from Child c where c.parentId = ?1")`
2. Lazy load the `BLOB` column whenever needed.

Note: depends to the situation you may wish to use cache for lazy loading. e.g. Guava library.

Comment: I think you meant `BLOB` not `BLOG` in your second bullet.